# How to get Point CSV extent with PyQgis

Tags: shapefile, pyqgis, csv, extents

I'm trying to get the extent of a point CSV file, but I can't do it.
Before in my script making, I did it with shapefile with :

```
reproj_1 = processing.runalg('qgis:reprojectlayer', point, 'EPSG:2154', None, progress=None)

enveloppe = processing.runalg('qgis:concavehull', reproj_1['OUTPUT'], 0.25, False, False, None, progress=None)

layer = processing.getObject(enveloppe['OUTPUT'])

ext = "%f,%f,%f,%f" %(layer.extent().xMinimum(), layer.extent().xMaximum(), layer.extent().yMinimum(), layer.extent().yMaximum())
```

And It work.
But now i'm using csv and it returns me this classical error : `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extent'`

Somebody have an idea ?

Comment: Have you tried Vector > Geometry Tools > Check Validity on the CSV layer?

Comment: I try to print `layer` and it returns `None`. That's maybe why there isn't extent... `enveloppe['OUTPUT']` isn't the good name for process output...

Comment: Can you save the csv as a shapefile?

Comment: At the beginning of my script it's shapefile and during my procces in the script I convert it in csv. When I did it manually before scripting it, I observed that csv conversion delete some geometry issues to use csv.

Comment: Please update your question and include the code related to getting extent on the csv layer object.  This will provide a better view of what you tried and the possible issue.